# Devices excluded GooglePlay based on Manifest - but device has SMS capabilities

Tags: android, sms, google-play

I have an app that sends SMS - so GooglePlay filters all devices that can send SMS.

But now I got a request from someone with an Acer 510 3G (which can send SMS) that my app is not shown for his device.

Is there anything one can do to make the app available for that device? Do these tablets actually send SMS the standard Android way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if the google play filters are wrong... (blame acer here for not telling google what hardware their device supports).

You might have to set [PackageManager#hasSystemFeature](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#hasSystemFeature%28java.lang.String%29) and set `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />` Then just stop the app working on devices that the PackageManger says has no telephony manager installed.

Little backwards but if the filtering is wrong on the play store you'll have to do it in a weird hacky way.

Comment: sorry Acer 510 3g, it says in the specs that it can send SMS too